# Understanding Hartshorne's example II 3.2.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, morphism

**Example 3.2.2.** If $P$ is a point of a variety $V$, with local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$, then $X:=\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_P$ is an integral noetherian scheme, which is not in general of finite type over $k$.

**First question:**
What does finite type over $k$ mean?

Is it that there must be a morphism from $k$ to $X$?

**Trying to understand the example:**
As $V$ is a variety, then $A(V)$ is a domain, so $A(V)_{\mathcal{m}_P}\cong \mathcal{O}_P$ (Theorem I.3.2 (c)) is a domain, so $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a domain, so $X$ is integral. As $ \mathcal{O}_P$ is noetherian, then $X$ is noetherian.

There is a isomorphism $A(V)\cong\mathcal{O}_P$ (Theorem I.3.2 (a)) and a map from $\mathcal{O}(V)\to \mathcal{O}_P$, so we get a map $A(V)\to \mathcal{O}_p$. On the other hand there is another map $k\to A(Y)$ so composing these maps I get
$$\varphi:k\to \mathcal{O}_P$$
Let $X:= \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_P$ and $Y:\operatorname{Spec} k$.
The map $f$ induces another map
$$f:X\to Y$$

But, $\mathcal{O}_P$ need not be necessarily a finitely generated $k$-algebra. So $f$ is not of finite type.

Is it ok?

**Edited**
If it is ok, is there any example of a variety $V$ such that $O_P$ is not a finitely generated $k-$algebra?

Thank you.

Comment: You can look up finite type practically anywhere, including in Hartshorne's book: the definition is in the middle of page 84.

Comment: @KReiser thank you for your answer, in the definitions it says: "A morphism $f:X\to Y$ is of finite type if ...".  Should it be, "a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is a finite type over $X$ if..."?

Comment: I mean, $f:X\to Y$ is a finite type over $Y$.

Comment: No, that's not how those words are used. You can say "$f$ is of finite type" or "$X$ is of finite type over $Y$".

Comment: @KReiser Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation for giving an explicit counterexample. Thinking in terms of affine varieties, we are looking for $V =\mathrm{Spec} A$ and a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$ such that:

1. $A$ is a finite type $k$-algebra;
2. the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ is not of finite type as a $k$-algebra.

I'll work in characteristic $0$ for simplicity's sake. If $k$ is an uncountable field of characteristic $0$ (think $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then you can consider $A = k[X]$, which is of obviously of finite type over $k$. The corresponding variety is the affine line $V:= \mathbb{A}_k^1$.

Localization of $A$ at $(X)$ gives you the *local ring at the origin* $k[X]_{(X)}$ of $k[X]$, *i.e.* take $P = (0)$, then $\mathcal{O}_P = k[X]_{(X)}$.

Now $k[X]_{(X)}$ is not of finite type over $k$, as pointed out in the second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616401/why-is-every-finitely-generated-field-over-k-not-a-finite-type-k-algebra). A way of seeing this is by looking at he dimension as a $k$-vector space: $\dim_k k[X]_{(X)}$ is uncountable, as it admits a free family $\left( \frac{1}{X-a} \right)_{a\in k^{\times}}$. On the other hand any finitely generated $k$-algebra has at most countable dimension over $k$ (being a quotient of a polynomial ring).

Thus $\mathrm{Spec} (k[X])$ is a variety over $k$, but $\mathrm{Spec} (\mathcal{O}_P )$ is not of finite type over $k$.

Comment: This is not correct: the localization of $A$ at $X$ is $k[x]_{(x)}$, which has non-invertible elements like $x$. The rest of the argument still works by considering $\frac{1}{x-a}$ as $a$ ranges over $k\setminus 0$.

Comment: Thanks and fixed! I actually meant to talk about the local ring of the generic point, but even though it is simpler algebra (fields of fractions are usually introduced before localization) maybe it is less confusing to think of the local ring at an "honest point". Regardless, both work and actually if $k$ is algebraically closed then none of the local rings of $\mathbf{A}_k^1$ are of finite type!